# React/Material-UI How to import Slider Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want to use the Slider Component provided by @material-ui/core in my react project, but if I import the [Slider](https://material-ui.com/components/slider/) like so: `import Slider from 'import Slider from '@material-ui/lab/Slider';` it does throw me the error `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'import Slider from '@material-ui/lab/Slider';`.

I am using `"@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3"`. Also looking in my node_modules package there is no slider comp.

Does any of you know what kind of extra dep. I need to install/use?

Comment: Can you tell us what is the installed package version of '@material-ui/core' in your node_modules? Did you try named imports like import { Slider } from "@material-ui/core";  ?

Comment: I think version "^3.9.3" does not contain sliders, try to update the  @material-ui/core to at least v4.0.2 . check out the versions of material-ui https://v3.material-ui.com/versions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should update the version to **v4.0** or above to import as `import Slider from '@material-ui/core/Slider';` or you can import like this:`import Slider from '@material-ui/lab/Slider';` in **v3.9.3** to use **Slider**

this caused because of Slider added to ***core*** directory after **v4.0**

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion there is no slider in version 3 of material-ui. You have to use version 4+ ;-)